# Omnichannel is stuck in busy status

Tags: omnichannel, chat, einstein-chatbot, einstein-bots

I recently created an Einstein bot, I am using OmniChannel to route it. when I set my Status to 'Online', it shows online but on the bottom it still says busy and it does not route the chat correctly.

Could this be due to creating too many messaging Sessions while testing (maybe capacity)? I deleted the messaging sessions records that were created but that did not resolve the issue.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to resolve this by going to the omnichannel supervisor tab and changing the status for the user who is stuck offline.

Answer (score 0):

This happened to me and it turns out I was just missing the Chat User checkbox on my user record. Checking that fixed the problem for me.